# Using GetLastError with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

A while back I wrote a simple wrapper class for the Windows API functions.  I wrote a set of unit tests to verify the class produces results matching direct calls to the API.

Recently I have gone back to add unit tests regarding the use of the wrapper class across different threads.  I found a few issues with the `::GetLastError` function.  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) the function should retain the last error code per thread:

> Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code.

I found that in some circumstances, the last error code actually becomes zero.  I have managed to replicate the problem outside of the unit tests with the below simple program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::DWORD setError1 = 123;
    ::DWORD setError2 = 456;

    // scenario 1 - show that main thread not polluted by sub-thread
    const auto act1 = [](::DWORD errorNo)
    {
        ::SetLastError(errorNo);
        const auto a = ::GetLastError(); // a = 123
    };

    ::SetLastError(setError2);
    const auto b = ::GetLastError(); // b = 456
    const auto c = ::GetLastError(); // c = 456
    std::thread sub1(act1, setError1);
    sub1.join();
    const auto d = ::GetLastError(); // d = 0 - WHY???


    // scenario 2 - show that sub thread not polluted by main thread
    std::condition_variable conditional;
    std::mutex mutex;
    bool flag = false;
    ::DWORD e;
    const auto act2 = [&mutex, &flag, &e, &conditional](::DWORD errorNo)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        ::SetLastError(errorNo);
        conditional.wait(lock, [&flag] { return flag; });
        e = ::GetLastError();  // e = 456 in Windows 8.1, 0 in Windows 10.0.10240.0 - WHY???
    };

    std::thread sub2(act2, setError2);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
        ::SetLastError(setError1);
        flag = true;
    }
    conditional.notify_all();
    sub2.join();
    const auto f = ::GetLastError();  // f = 123;
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is with `d` and `e`:

- d - I found that the last error code for the *main thread* sees a reset to zero when using a sub-thread.
- e - When using the Windows 10 SDK, I found that the *sub-thread* sees a reset of the last error to zero whilst waiting on the `std::condition_variable`.  This doesn't reset when using the Windows 8.1 SDK.

Could someone help explain the results I am seeing?  Is this a bug in the Windows API, a bug in Microsoft's implementation of C++?  Or a bug in my own code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple enough. Here's what happens:

1. You call `SetLastError`.
2. You call another function which in turn calls `SetLastError`.
3. You call `GetLastError` and get the latest value, which was the value set in item 2 and not in item 1.

So, looking at your code, with my annotations:

```
::SetLastError(setError2);          // item 1 from the list above
std::thread sub1(act1, setError1);  // item 2
sub1.join();                        // item 2
const auto d = ::GetLastError();    // item 3
```

And your other example:

```
 ::SetLastError(errorNo);                          // item 1
 conditional.wait(lock, [&flag] { return flag; }); // item 2
 e = ::GetLastError();                             // item 3
```

In each of these cases, your code that I have annotated as *item 2* is calling API functions that in turn call `SetLastError`.

Comment: So Microsoft's implementation of the standard library, or at least its implementation of threading, uses the Windows API?

Comment: For sure. You cannot create a thread without going through the Windows API. And likewise for synchronisation objects. These will be implemented on top of the system objects where possible.

Comment: ^^ what David says.  I/O, threads, inter-thread synchro etc. MUST be managed by the OS else chaos will ensue.   If you make an API call, either explicitly or indirectly via a library, and it fails, you should call GetLastError as the very next step else you risk losing the error information to another API that succeeds.

Comment: @CamelCase: Visual Studio comes with (almost) complete source code to the CRT and the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @MartinJames - Yes, any call we have to get last error is immediately after the API call.  This was purely raised from unit testing our function wrapper.  I was unaware that the error code is also subject to updates when using std classes/functions.  A link to this answer is currently embedded into my code comments (specifically why I expect a return of zero at certain points).